# Javascript and Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have 3 Javascripts on my site. They are all for social media sharing. All work perfectly in Safari, Chrome and Edge.

However Internet Explorer throws up a error on two of the three.

The one that works on all is below.

```
function fbshareCurrentPage(){window.open("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="+escape(window.location.href)+"&t="+document.title,"","menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600")}
```

This is called by a button with the link javascript:fbshareCurrentPage()

As said the above works on all browsers that I have tested. But the Twitter and Google plus scripts does not work on IE but works on Chrome and Safari etc.

```
var twitterHandle = 'HANDLE';

function tweetCurrentPage() {
    window.open('https://twitter.com/share?url='+escape(window.location.href)+'&text='+document.title + ' via @' + twitterHandle, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');
    return false;
}
```

Called in the same way as the Facebook one.. javascript:tweetCurrentPage()

Google Plus script is

```
function john() {
  var w = 380;
  var h = 480;
  var x = Number((window.screen.width - w) / 2);
  var y = Number((window.screen.height - h) / 2);
  window.open("https://plus.google.com/share?url=" +
    encodeURIComponent(location.href) +
    "&title=" + 
    encodeURIComponent(document.title),
    "",
    "width=" + w +",height=" + h + ",left=" + x + ",top=" + y +",resizable=yes"
  );
}
```

Called by a button with the link javascript:john()

In Chrome they all open in popup windows as I want and function correctly. In IE the google plus and twitter links open in a new tab with the below error.

> This page can’t be displayed
>
> •Make sure that the web address //ieframe.dll/dnserror.htm# is correct.
> •Look for the page with your search engine.

What am I doing wrong?

I am learning more and more about JavaScript but would appreciate some help.

Thanks

Comment: You said IE throws an error but you didn't provide the error you got.

Comment: Yes..the error is the tab opens but shows "This page cannot be displayed" and the IEframe error. But the Facebook one works fine even tho the script is called in the same fashion.

Comment: MSIE browsers use Security zones and there are restrictions navigating to sites in zones of lower integrity (intranet to internet) and the built-in popup blocker or addons can alter the outcomes for scripted windows (windows.open). Use the File>Properties menu to determine the IE security zone your test environment is using.... Don't place any domains in the IE Trusted Sites list. click "Reset all zones to default" (security tab of Internet Options) and don't place social buttons on login screens.

Comment: Ok well I also installed Firefox and and the result is the same. Facebook link works and the other two don't

Comment: The value of the property 'tweetCurrentPage' is null or undefined, not a Function object